# What is the volatility surface of a parameter that depends on a Stochastic process?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Hi this question takes a few steps to setup so please bear with me :)

**Short version:**
Does a parameter that depends on the output of a stochastic model inherently have variance? If so why?

**Long version with an example:** 
Say that interest rates are modeled by using a standard stochastic model (ex: Vasicek 1 factor). The following steps are taken:

```
1-Monte Carlo is used to simulate the interest rates 100 times. 

2-Future cash flows are discounted using each of the simulated rate paths. 

3-Each of the 100 simulations is given a score of 1 or 0 if the sum of the 
discounted cash flows is less than or greater than current assets respectively. 

4-The 1's and 0's are used to give a probability that assets > liabilities. 
In our example let's say it was 96%. Assume that the target was 90% so in our 
case the test passes.
```

Now say that as part of the model, each cash flow can be adjusted by Factor >=1 but initially Factor is set to 1. At this point, we do not rerun the simulations. We just adjust this Factor until the 96% probability decreases to 90% and find that Factor is 1.21.

**My question is**, does Factor inherently have variance since it is dependent on the output of the stochastic model? What happens if Factor can be capped at 1.15?

I think it does in the sense that there is stochastic noise from the Brownian motion of the Vasicek. However, this is a single point value. At the stage when Factor is calculated, the result is deterministic and has no variance...

Thanks!